# vue question: rendering components dynamically?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to vue and programming in general and I would like to know how to go about this problem please ?

For example,I have 10 components, each one of those 10 components has a component inside it called (ABC)

inside (ABC), there is a component inside called (XYZ) and (XYZ) component has props on it that recieve data properties from (ABC)

I want (ABC) to appear in all components as it is now, but to show the (XYZ) component inside it in certain components only in the 10 components mentioned above.

How would I do that please ?

have not tried yet, but I think slots would be the answer but I do not know how to inplement it in this situation

Comment: Can you please provide some more context? What have you already tried? Some code snippets would help to understand your expectation.

Comment: Use the StackOverflow search first and elaborate why you didn't find the solution there. See [SO search: rendering vue components dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rendering+vue+components+dynamically). *"have not tried yet"* - and you expect us to write all that for you? Please at least make an attempt. No need to implement all 10 components, just have to prove it works with 2 or 3 then it'll work with any number if you plan for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you can add a prop to component ABC. The with the ABC component you can use this prop as a boolean in a v-if on component XYZ. Then set the prop on each ABC component.

// Where you define the components

```
<abc flag="true" />
```

// In ABC component

```
<xyz v-if="flag">

props : {
  flag: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  }
}
```